# NDK build failed while building Cocos2d-js hello world

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-js

I'm just getting started with Cocos2d and was trying to compile and deploy the hello world example. It works fine for web deployment, but with android it fails with the following error.

```
>> cocos compile -p android

>> Android NDK: ERROR:E:/workspace/android-ndk-r10/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/Android.mk:gnustl_static: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
>> Android NDK: Check that E:/workspace/android-ndk-r10/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/clang3.4/libs/armeabi/thumb/libgnustl_static.a exists  or that its path is correct
```

When I look in the folder "E:/workspace/android-ndk-r10/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++", I don't see clang3.4 in it... but how do I fix this problem? I am using the latest NDK (r10).
I am on Windows 7 64 bit, and the NDK I downloaded is also for 64bit (android-ndk64-r10-windows-x86_64).

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I believe you need NDK9. I'll see what I can find out. In the meantime, I would reccomend asking in the [official forums](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/category/javascript).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, will try out NDK9.

Comment: Yes, I changed also back to NDK9. A cocos developer recommended.